# Use intuition, It causes a schism. Entity?

Tags: riddle, word

In your mind I manifest
Understanding of me is vague at best

I'm said to take away the order
Less likey to be seen in the daughter

Heightened moods wont decide your fate
When held onto, is my traits

White cloaks might give you sensations
Line them up for no frustrations

For some I am not what I envision
Yet oppression is used to describe my prison

Give it a go and see if you can match every line to the answer. Please if you do answer explain how you arrived at it and how it manages to describe each line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thought of

> autism

In your mind I manifest

> this so-called disease doesn't affect the body but the brain only, I assume

Understanding of me is vague at best

> the people suffering from it are often considered geniuses, hard to catch up with their mental level

I'm said to take away the order

> Well, nothing to be added here from my point of view

Less likely to be seen in the daughter

> As far as I know, females have lower risk of being autistic ("artistic" ? ;))

Heightened moods wont decide your fate

> autism is said to be almost unaffected by hightened moods like happiness

When held onto, is my traits

> 

White cloaks might give you sensations

> doctors/scientists give cognitive behavioral therapy, range of medicine (?)

Line them up for no frustrations

> Line them up in the right order alphabetically or colour, which ever is the right compulsion

For some I am not what I envision

> many think of 'handy caps' as they are all the same :( (autistic movements to change the way we perceive autism as many believe its not a disability)

Yet oppression is used to describe my prison

> disabled people are not fully integrated and seen as kind of lesser entities by many (Autism forces "sufferers" into their own mind and are unusual to start a conversation/relationship with other"

Answer (score 1):

All right, I'm giving this a go -

> Anxiety

In your mind I manifest
Understanding of me is vague at best

> It is a mental disorder, fight vs flight response. But it is difficult to pinpoint the cognitive or phisiological causes for a general population

I'm said to take away the order

> Anxiety and panic tend to create chaos in the mind. It's difficult to reason with internally.

Less likey to be seen in the daughter

> Males under 18 are more likely to show aggression and other symptoms of anxiety than females<sup>[1](http://www.apa.org/news/press/releases/2011/08/mental-illness.aspx)</sup>, though mental disorders of this nature is generally diagnosed more often in females.

Heightened moods wont decide your fate
When held onto, is my traits

> Mood stabilizers and other medicine can only have an effect if the root-cause of the anxiety, and in turn also the tendencies, are also addressed

White cloaks might give you sensations
Line them up for no frustrations

> Mental health doctors and therapists have a lot of different methods of diagnosis and can provide relief from the anxiety with therapy and medicine

For some I am not what I envision

> Some envision anxiety as panic, but it can present much differently among people

Yet oppression is used to describe my prison

> Living with anxiety feels like a prison because of the way it changes everything everyday.

I think the last line for me is the weakest. I highly doubt this is correct, but I couldn't resist seeing if it fit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, well thought out I have had a look into your reasoning and it seems anxiety effects woman more than men as a disorder. your explanation didnt relate to "Line them up for no frustration". Your explanation for "heightened moods wont decide your fate" also seems to be off.